# How can i get array key-values pair using javascript

Tags: javascript

```
for(i=0;i<=array_values.length;i++){ 
   var a=array_values[i].amounts; 
   var t=array_values[i].Tax; 
   alert(a); 
   alert(t); 
}
```

Error : TypeError: array_values[i] is undefined

```
var a=array_values[i].amounts;
var a=array_values[i].amounts;
```

Comment: You should read this as a guide to asking good questions on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Good questions that are clear and concise will often get you better quality answers, faster.

Comment: Sorry, this question is a bit confusing.

First of all, how did you created and populated array_values? We need some more code to understand...

Also, what are the last two lines? 

And what's the question? I mean, I probably understood it by the title, but clearer is your request, easier is you have a good answer :)

Comment: You need to initialize array_values before the 'for' loop.

Comment: Please format your code with the tools available to increase readability and read @Matt-SL's reading recommendation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
for(i=0;i<=array_values.length;i++)
```

to

```
for(i=0;i<array_values.length;i++)
```

`<=` to `<`